# PHP - Switch values inside of a for loop

Tags: php, json, for-loop, foreach, switch-statement

I'm coding a page using PHP.

I can get a list of categories via JSON (external, that I can't modify). Each category has an ID and a name. I'm retrieving the list using a foreach:

```
$jsonCategoriesDecode = json_decode($jsonCategories, true);
foreach ($categories as $category){
    $category['id'] = $category['name'];
    }
```

On another area of my code, I have a `for loop` to get another type of information via JSON (also external).
But here I have only access to the *Category ID* (not to the *Category Name*).

```
$jsonLatest = json_decode($latest, true);
for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {
    $topic_category[$i] = $jsonLatest['topic_list']['topics'][$i]['category_id'];
    echo $topic_category[$i];
}
```

**What I want is to show the *Category Name* inside the for loop (instead of the *Category ID*).**

I tried the following:

```
$jsonLatest = json_decode($latest, true);
for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {
    $topic_category[$i] = $jsonLatest['topic_list']['topics'][$i]['category_id'];

    // Translate the category ID to Name
    foreach ($jsonCategoriesDecode['category_list']['categories'] as $category){
        $category['id'] = $category['name'];
        $topic_category[$i] = $category['id'];
        echo $category['name'];

    }
}
```

But the output is a list of names for all the categories.
I just want the name of the `$topic_category[$i]`

I played with the `switch` statement, but I haven't had any luck. I can't hardcode all the *Category IDs* and their corresponding *Category Names* because I will create more in the future, so it needs to be automated. That's why I'm trying to use the `foreach loop`.

**How can I translate that *Category ID* into the *Category Name*?**

**EDIT:**
The main problem is that I can't get the Category Name on on the $jsonLatest, only the ID.

I can't change the JSON contents because they are external. That's why I'm thinking that perhaps using the other JSON (where I can get both ID and Name) will help to translate that ID into the Name on the $jsonLatest.

The foreach loop, it's just for that, it doesn't do anything else on my code. I can even delete it

**EDIT 2:** Added source links

Json files:
https://forum.illustration.tools/latest.json
https://forum.illustration.tools/categories.json

Php file:
pastebin.com/bmX8TAaj

Answer (score 1):

The right way is a matter of opinion.

I would definately not do a foreach loop inside a for loop (or any two nestled loops of any kind for that matter) if it can be avoided. Which it can for your case.

This is not because of it being wrong, but because it increases time complexity in your code. As the arrays grow bigger, your code will execute **exponentially** slower.

Now, this is still an opinion, and you will have to decide for yourself. Perhaps you know that these json objects will not grow big over time, and perhaps memory is a key concern for your script. In that case, stick to another solution.

However, this is how I would solve it.

```
$jsonCategories = json_decode('https://forum.illustration.tools/categories.json', true);
$jsonLatest = json_decode('https://forum.illustration.tools/latest.json', true);

$categoryNames = array();
foreach ($jsonCategories['category_list']['categories'] as $category) {
    $categoryNames[$category['id']] = $category['name'];
}

for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {
    $topic_category[$i] = $jsonLatest['topic_list']['topics'][$i]['category_id'];
    echo $categoryNames[$topic_category[$i]], PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The main problem is that I can't get the Category Name on on the $jsonLatest, only the ID. And I can't change the JSON contents because it's external. That's why I'm thinking that perhaps using the other JSON (where I can get both ID and Name) will help to translate that ID into the Name on the $jsonLatest.

The foreach loop, it's just for that, it doesn't do anything else on my code. I can even delete it.

I tried your code but the output is empty. Do you have another option of how can I do that _translation_ of category ID into Name?

Comment: Can you give an example on how $latest and $jsonCategories looke like? When I test this exact same code on these two structures it works: [{'id': 10, 'name': 'foo'},{'id': 20, 'name': 'bar'},{'id': 30, 'name': 'taz'},{'id': 40, 'name': 'dep'},{'id': 50, 'name': 'biz'},{'id': 60, 'name': 'hup'}] and 
{'topic_list': {'topics': [{'category_id': 60},{'category_id': 50},{'category_id': 40},'category_id': 30},{'category_id': 20},{'category_id': 10}]}}

Comment: Here are both JSON:
https://forum.illustration.tools/latest.json
https://forum.illustration.tools/categories.json

And here is my full file:
https://pastebin.com/bmX8TAaj

Thanks for your help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Ok, I updated the solution to match with your datastructure. The reason it didn't work was because I assumed jsonCategories was a top level array of category objects.

Comment: Mmmm it doesn't work. Apparently, there is an error, perhaps there is a typo? http://codepad.org/lTfKJvwI

Thanks again!

Comment: I'm trying to fix the error, but I haven't had any luck.
The error is: **Cannot use string offset as an array** referring to the line _foreach ($jsonCategories['category_list']['categories'] as $category) {_
Thanks again for your help!